# Resize Div within div with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, resize

Hi I have a main div that hosts 2 other divs. The lower one is to change height depending on the resize of the main div size.

Here is the code as far as I got it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #upper{
            background:#F00;
            border: black solid 2px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            height: 50px;
        }
         #lower{
            background:#AAF;
            border: red solid 2px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
        #maindiv{
            height: 100%;
            border: green solid 2px
        }
        html,body{margin: 0px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body id="bodyId" > 
<div id="maindiv">

    <div id="upper">test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    v
    test<br/>
    test<br/></div>

    <div id="lower" onresize="resize('lower')">test2</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resize(arg)
        {
            var frame= document.getElementById(arg);
            var heights= document.getElementById(arg).parentNode.offsetHeight ;
            alert(frame);
            frame.style.height = heights -50 + "px";


        }



    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

FOr some reason it doesn't work. I want to get the lower divs id (lower) to the function and get the parent divs id (maindiv) and its height. With that I want to set the height of the lower div.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

TheVagabond

Comment: Have you looked into just using CSS media queries to achieve this result?

Comment: No. I only got the above. But how would that help me?

Comment: Would you like me to answer with media queries alternative?

Comment: Sure I try that. Always good to learn something new

Comment: You can try by adding the  onresize="resize('lower')" on the body tag.

Comment: @Raj that only resizes the main div making it 50px smaller every time but the lower div is unchanged

Comment: What is this being used for? Is it to handle screen resizing?

Comment: @F.Bar yes. I want the main div and the upper one to stray with fixed height and the lower should adapt to the size of the browser window

Comment: @Thevangabond you are resizing the mainDiv on your resize function frame.style.height = heights -50 + "px"; Instead try document.getElementById(arg).style.height = heights -50 + "px";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle changes in screen sizes is using media queries in your css.

W3 schools is a good place to [start](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

A quick example, take the parent div and 2 child:

```
<div id="parentContainer">
  <div id="d1"> </div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
```

We can style the above using:

```
#parentContainer {
  border:1px solid red; 
  height:100%; 
  width:300px; 
}

#d1 {
  width:300px; 
  height:300px; 
  background-color:green; 
}

#d2 {
  width:300px; 
  height:300px; 
  background-color:orange;
}
```

Now, with media queries, we can make some changes to the styling dending on screen sizing:

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
  #parentContainer {
    height:100%; 
  }

  #d1, #d2 {
    height:50%; 
  }
}
```

In this example, we are saying WHEN the screen size is 400px change the height of the parent to 100% and make the child divs both 50% each.

By doing this, each time the screen size decreases, so do the divs, dynamically.

Comment: I have to look into this. Thanks.

Comment: It's a more efficient way of creating dynamic web pages. If you need further help I'd be happy to assist :)

Comment: When using your example I get the starting divs but they stay with 300px when resizing.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/jexp4dyh/3/)

Comment: Try changing the media max-width to max-height if you're resizing the screen height ways.

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: I've just tested on mine and it does work. You need to resize the height of whatever you're browsing in down to at least 400px to see the difference.

Here: https://codedump.io/share/3vrcI1Yt9fVS/1/dynamic-resize

Comment: Glad I could help :) But definatly worth while looking into media queries!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #upper{
            background:#F00;
            border: black solid 2px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            height: 50px;
        }
         #lower{
            background:#AAF;
            border: red solid 2px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
        #maindiv{
            height: 100%;
            border: green solid 2px
        }
        html,body{margin: 0px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body id="bodyId" onresize="resize('lower')"> 
<div id="maindiv">

    <div id="upper">test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    v
    test<br/>
    test<br/></div>

    <div id="lower">test2</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resize(arg)
        {
            var frame= document.getElementById(arg);
            var heights= frame.parentNode.offsetHeight;
            frame.style.height = heights -70 + "px";


        }



    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

@Raj was right with the body, I just had some wrong adressing inside the script part.

@F. Bar I will look into the media query, however I don't have a starting height for the lower div SO I have to play with that. Thanks however point out about the media query at all, haven't heared of that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `parentElement` instead of `parentNode`.
Here is a snippet with a button for test resize.
You can call a function everytime on event when the upper div height changes.

```js
function resize(arg)
{
  var frame= document.getElementById(arg);
  var heights= document.getElementById(arg).parentElement.clientHeight;
  frame.style.height = heights -50 + "px";
}
```

```css
#upper{
  background:#cca;
  border: black solid 2px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lower{
  background:#9c9;
  border: red solid 2px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#maindiv{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border: green solid 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">

    <div id="upper">test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    v
    test<br/>
    test<br/></div>

    <div id="lower">test2</div>
    <button onclick="resize('lower')">resize</button>
</div>
```